# singular $m$-canonical divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

[remark for v2] I began by considering curves in v1. I am convinced that the answer is positive. Thanks to Jason Starr and abx.

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety.
Let $K_X$ be its canonical bundle.

Let $m$ be an integer.
We assume that a generic element in the linear system $|mK_X|$ is a smooth divisor.
Let $S\subseteq|mK_X|$ be the set of singular divisors.

Is $S$ always a hypersurface, i.e., without irreducible component of codimension $\geqslant 2$ ?
If it is the case, could we calculate the degree of $S$ ?

Comment: Regarding your general question: I believe that every "tangent defective" variety is uniruled.  Every variety with nontrivial pluricanonical sections, i.e., with nonnegative Kodaira dimension, is non-uniruled.  Thus, no such variety can be "tangent defective".

Comment: For your first question, you can just "count" the degree of this hypersurface to see that it is not codimension 2, cf. the following MO answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165672/bounding-the-number-of-critical-points-in-a-lefschetz-pencil

Comment: For cuves,this is all very classical. See for instance Arbarello et al., chap. VIII, §5 ("de Jonquières formula").